# How to edit Google Adsense?

Tags: adsense

I am trying to find out if one can still edit their google ads. I would like mine to appear how i have it below.

- Two Ads (and no more), Pure text (no arrows), and the "Ads by Google" on top. Is there something i am missing?? do i have to be a premium member?? Please help.

Ads by Google

`Title to Ad`

`The description of the ad on this line.`

`www.examplead.com`

`Title to Ad`

`The description of the ad on this line.`

`www.examplead.com`

Comment: I understand why it was closed. Ive only been programming for a little over a year now (self-taught) and was unclear as to whether I could edit it with javascript or not.

Comment: mtokoly, I'm glad you understand why it was closed, because I don't.

Comment: This seems like it should be a superuser question, not a stack overflow question. If this is about *programmatically* making those modifications, please edit your question to reflect such.

Comment: yeah, i meant to say "I don't understand" - how else would one edit code Randolpho? ...with magic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alter the way the ads look only in the ways your adsense admin panel allows.

According to the T&C, you shouldn't be altering the code Google gives you for an ad unit.

You'll need a whole lot of traffic to your ads to be able to do more (then Google will work with you more directly).

Comment: That's what I feared, thanks John. I understand that AdBrite allows you to customize it, what is your take on using it??

Comment: Haven't used AdBrite.  Sorry!